# Change style output to make it not underline

Tags: html, css

I have new to CSS / HTML , sorry to ask such question .

I want to have a CSS / HTML code to make the word "testing" do not have underline , but I still find the underline on the web page , would advise how to change it to make it work ?

```
<a style="a:link {text-decoration:none;}" href="http://example.com" >testing</a>
```

Comment: You want the link to have underline but no underline when you mouse over it?

Answer (score 2):

you need to change this

```
<a style="a:link {text-decoration:none;}" href="http://example.com" >testing</a>
```

to this

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://example.com" >testing</a>
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/K6CdG/

Answer (score 1):

If you add a style property to an HTML object, you don't have to add the CSS Selector. The style property in an HTML object only works for that particular object.
So in your case you only have to add `style="text-decoration:none;"` into the HTML object.
However, if you don't want text-decoration in every `<a>` objects on the page, you have to add the CSS within the `<style>` tags in the `<head>` tags.

```
<style>
    a {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
</style>
```

You could also link to an external CSS page. Most people prefer this to keep their document structured. To achieve this you have to add the following code in the `<head>` tags:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Change `href=style.css` to the file name of your CSS file (.css file extension included).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way as well if you want to change it just **only for this anchor tag**.

```
<a class="myUndecoratedLink" href="http://example.com" >testing</a>
```

Define below style either in a external CSS file or in your HTML.

```
.myUndecoratedLink,.myUndecoratedLink:HOVER {
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

**Try to define style in external file instead of inline styling as you are doing to make it more manageable.**

In this way you can benefit of **Themes** be creating different CSS files one for each theme.

For more info have a look at below post:

- [The 3 ways to insert CSS into your web pages](http://www.csstutorial.net/css_misc_inserting.php)
- [CSS How To...](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)